# Issue in code regarding functions (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the most part, my code works. If you run it and don't make any mistake in input, it works as intended. If your input is wrong, it says the appropriate message and prompts you to input again, but if you then input a valid number, it breaks down with the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seren\Documents\~School~\MSON Intro Computer Programming\Earthquake.py", line 92, in <module>
    print(r.yourQuakeOutput())
  File "C:\Users\Seren\Documents\~School~\MSON Intro Computer Programming\Earthquake.py", line 49, in yourQuakeOutput
    joules = r.calcJoules()
  File "C:\Users\Seren\Documents\~School~\MSON Intro Computer Programming\Earthquake.py", line 18, in calcJoules
    return 10 ** ((1.5 * self.r) + 4.8)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

I don't understand at all what this means, or how to fix it. I think it has something to do with the yourQuakeInput function, but I'm not sure. Does anyone have an idea? Here's the code itself:

```
 class Earthquakes:

    def __init__(self, richter):
        self.r = richter

    def calcJoules(self):
        return 10 ** ((1.5 * self.r) + 4.8)

    def calcTNT(self):
        joules = r.calcJoules()
        return joules/(4.184 * 10 ** 9)

    def genericQuake(self):
        joules = r.calcJoules()
        tnt = r.calcTNT()
        return "An earthquake with a %s on the Richter scale is equivalent to %s joules and %s tons of exploded TNT." % (self.r, joules, tnt)

    def specQuake(self, quake):
        joules = r.calcJoules()
        tnt = r.calcTNT()
        return "The %s earthquake, a %s on the Richter scale, was equivalent to %s joules and %s tons of exploded TNT." % (quake, self.r, joules, tnt)

    def yourQuakeInput(self):
        richter = float(input("Your earthquake measures what on the Richter scale?"))
        if richter < 0:
            print("The Richter scale only goes from 0-10. Try again.")
            r.yourQuakeInput()
        elif richter > 10:
            print("The Richter scale only goes from 0-10. Try again.")
            r.yourQuakeInput()
        elif richter >= 0 and richter <= 10:
            return richter
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Try again.")
            r.yourQuakeInput()

    def yourQuakeOutput(self):
        joules = r.calcJoules()
        tnt = r.calcTNT()
        return "Your earthquake, a %s on the Richter scale, is equivalent to %s joules and %s tons of exploded TNT." % (self.r, joules, tnt)

    def __str__(self):
        return "richter=" + str(self.r)

def tryAgain():
    answer = input("Would you like to try again?").lower()
        if answer == "yes":
            pass
        elif answer == "no":
            quit()
        else: 
            print("Invalid input. Try again.")
            tryAgain()

r = Earthquakes (1.0)
print(r.genericQuake())
print("")

r = Earthquakes (5.0)
print(r.genericQuake())
print("")

r = Earthquakes (9.1)
print(r.specQuake("2004 Indonesia"))
print("")

r = Earthquakes (9.2)
print(r.specQuake("1964 Alaska"))
print("")

r = Earthquakes (9.5)
print(r.specQuake("1960 Chile"))
print("")

r = Earthquakes (5.8)
print(r.specQuake("2011 Virginia"))
print("")

while True:
    r = Earthquakes (r.yourQuakeInput())
    print(r.yourQuakeOutput())
    print("")

    tryAgain()
```

Comment: Did you really hard-code a global name of an object instance into the class?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, what exactly did you input

Comment: @mangoHero1 - When the input is good, `yourQuakeInput` does `return richter`. Otherwise, it just does `r.yourQuakeInput()` with no `return`, so that's why it's `None`. Overall, though, OP needs to review how to use classes and `self`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Did I? I'm new at this. And thank you for the answer. Can you explain the classes and self stuff? I'm kind of confused, hence the code.

Comment: This isn't a suitable venue for explaining these concepts. What you need is a tutorial or guide. The [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html) is good.

Comment: Alright. From what I'm seeing, I just shouldn't have used a class with this. But, well, I needed to put a class in one of my old programs for an assignment so I'll keep it anyway. It works. Will keep in mind what classes are for in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you are missing return statments if your anwser are incorrect:

```
if richter < 0:
    print("The Richter scale only goes from 0-10. Try again.")
    return r.yourQuakeInput()
elif richter > 10:
    print("The Richter scale only goes from 0-10. Try again.")
    return r.yourQuakeInput()
```

Comment: I like how ppl are downoatng corrent and accepted anwsers. /s